# the relationship between fractional difference and ACF of a time sequence

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, time-series

When reading the GARCH modeling part of book `Analysis of Financial Time Series`, I read the following statement. In specific, I do not understand how does the author get that statement marked with yellow. How to get the relationship between the fractional difference with `the ACF of` $u_t$.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using binomial expansion the fractional difference operator $(1-L)^d$ can be rewritten as
$$(1-L)^d = \sum_{j=0}^\infty a^d_j L^j$$. One can show that the coefficients $a_j^d$ satisfy
$$a_j^d \sim \frac{1}{\Gamma(d)} j^{-1-d} \qquad\text{for } j\rightarrow\infty.$$ As a result, the acf of $u_t$ shows the same asymptotic behavior. For more details, see for example Time Series: Theory and Methods by Brockwell and Davis.